# How does one produce a reactive confidence interval in a Shiny output?

Tags: r

I'm attempting to build a Shiny app that can be used to explore a dataset, and ultimately produce a 95% confidence interval for a single variable.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm unsure of how to filter the dataset, produce a 95% confidence interval using a t-test, then push that output to the app.

My dataset is called "flowers". It has a column with many "Month" observations, and a column with values corresponding to the number of flowers needed in a given month.

I appreciate any feedback. Thanks for your help.

```
# Load libraries
library(broom)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
  titlePanel("Confidence Interval"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select the desired model parameters 
               from the dropdown menus below."),

      selectInput(inputId = "month", 
                  label = "Choose a Month:",
                  choices = unique(data$Month),
                  selected = "January"),

    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Subset data
  CI <- reactive({flowers %>%
    filter(month == input$Month) %>%
    t.test(flowers$Lbs, data = flowers, conf.level = 0.95)
    })

  output$CI <- CI$conf.int

  output$text <- renderText({ 
    paste("There is a 95% probability that between" [lower estimate], "and", [upper estimate] "flowers will be needed in a given", strong(input$month), ".")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, 
         server = server)
```